# synchronize files from remote server with rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a question about rsync. I have two servers. I would like to run a rsync command on server 1 that synchronizes all data/files on server 2 to my server. Say I have on server 2 a folder /var/www/html/hello/* All files should be synchronized with the permissions from server 2 to server 1 but the command must be executed on server 1.  How can I do this with rsync ?

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -ai user2@server2:/var/www/html/hello/ local/directory/hello
```

This would connect using SSH to `server2` as user `user2`.  This user must have access to all the files and directories that will be copied.  The directory contents of `/var/www/html/hello/` will be replicated under `local/directory/hello` on the local machine.

Note the trailing `/` on the source directory path.  Without this, you would put the files and directories into a directory called `hello` in the destination folder.

If you add `--delete`, you would additionally remove local files in the destination directory that are not available on the source side.

The `-i` option turns on a itemisation of the things that are getting transferred.  Some people like using `-v` instead of `-i`.  The `-a` option is the option that preserves as much as possible of permissions and other meta-data, and also enables recursive replication of files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

rsync behaves like a simple copy programm. So syncing from remote is like (without additional options like recourse or permissions ...)

```
rsync remoteuser@remoteserver:/var/www/html/hello/* /to/local/folder/
```

This will copy the remote files - not folders to your local folder.

Use the options *-avz* to archive a kind of backup (include permissions and so on):

```
rsync -avz remoteSource localDestination
```

For more options see man page ...

**Edit 1:**

Please consider first comment from kusalananda about using the tailing `*` at source folder.

Comment: Note that by using `*`, you will skip transferring any hidden files. Use `rsync -a --exclude='*/' remote@remote:/var/www/html/hello/ local/folder` to transfer all the files in that single directory.